# Why is javascript functions not working after adding another function with an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had two javascript functions that added text input values to an input `type=select` between `<script>` tags.

After I added one more function, the above functions stopped working.
I found that the error was that I had forgotten the 0 in the if logical block. But this function with an error was at no point executed.

The thing I want to know is why would a function that is not called cause other functions to not operate?

Code of javascript functions that worked

```
function addCompanyFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("companylist");
          var txt = document.getElementById("taname");
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          if (txt.value != "") {
              option.text = txt.value;
              x.add(option, x[0]);
              }
        }
        function addCultFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("cultlist");
          var txt = document.getElementById("cultname");
          var option = document.createElement("option");

          if (txt.value != "") {
              option.text = txt.value;
              x.add(option, x[0]);
              }
        }
```

After adding the following function with its error the other functions stopped working

```
function filled_out(dict) {
    var i;
    if (dict.length > ) { //<--- the zero is missing which caused the problem
        for (var key in dict) {
            if (dict[key] == "") {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it is a SyntaxError. And a SyntaxError happens at parsing time and will prevent the whole block of code that is parsed from being executed.

Comment: Thanks that explains it.  I read a bit futher and found that when a syntax error occurs in JavaScript, only the code contained within the same thread as the syntax error is affected.  Very interesting.  Thanks again.